# How to shift puppeteers focus to a pop up window

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to run a test within a website. Once a button has been clicked, a new popup browser window appears with a report. Within that new window is information I'd like to extract. How can I get puppeteer to shift it's focus to this newly created browser window?

I have multiple print buttons on my puppeteer page clicking on which creates a popup, I am trying to get a pdf of those pages. Here is the code I am using.

```
let printButtons = await this.page.$$('#printNowButton');
for (var i = 0; i < printButtons.length; i++) {
    printButtons[i].click();
    const fileName = ('Document'+ i + '.pdf');
    browser.on('targetcreated', async target => {
        if ((target.url() !== 'about:blank')) {
            try {
                const pageList = await browser.pages();
                const newPage = await pageList[pageList.length - 1];
                await newPage.pdf({
                    path: fileName,
                    format: 'A4'
                }).then(() => {
                    newPage.close();
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am using puppeteer version 0.13.0
Any other way to obtain what I am trying to achieve is also appreciated.

Comment: If you have found a solution please do update.

Comment: Post your code so that people willing to help gets some more insight of the scenario.

Comment: You may need to do this in 2 steps. Click all buttons then wait and then loop through the pages array after all the tabs have finished loading, e.g.  `let pages = await browser.pages();`

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios in you case 
First,If you are using version less than v0.13.0 you won't be able to do it
Second if you are using node version 6 you have to build node components manually

```
cd node_modules/puppeteer
npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar use case where I'm testing a page that opens a new window via window.open, and I need to find it after to run some tests. Adding a listener for "targetcreated" works, as long as you register the listener before opening the new window.

This is my test runner which does the following:

1. Adds a listener for the "targetcreated" event, in which it:
2. Finds the newly opened page object
3. Runs some tests on the opened page.
4. Finally, a call to "openSearchWindow" which actually triggers the window.open.

Here is the test runner. I've replaced my own code with comments to make it easier for you to use.

```
await browser.on('targetcreated', async () => {
    const foundPage = await changePage(theNewURLOfThePopUpWindow);
    if(foundPage) {
        //Run some basic tests on the new page
        const hasLoaded = await runSomeTestsHere();
        expect(hasLoaded).to.be.true;
        done();
    } else {
        done('Failed to find new page.');
    }
});
//Opens the new popup window by clicking a button
await openSearchWindow(page);
```

changePage is a simple function that loops through all open browser pages and saves the page object for the page with a matching url. After running this you can use the new page for your tests, if it is opened.

```
async function changePage(url) {
    let pages = await browser.pages();
    let foundPage = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < pages.length; i += 1) {
        if(pages[i].url() === url) {
            foundPage = true;
            module.exports.page = pages[i];//set the new working page as the popup
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundPage;
}
```